# Fourier sum of sines and how to evaluate this

Tags: fourier-analysis

here, i know that

$$ 0=\frac{1}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}cos(nx) $$

so by simple integration term by term on the series

$$ \frac{A-x}{2}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(nx)}{n} $$

so if i put x=0 the sum of sines is 0 and i get A=0

and so if i integrate another time i get

$$ \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{Ax}{2}+B =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{cos(nx)}{n^2}$$

then which are A and B ??

Comment: $A$ is still $0$, as it is the same as above. You will get $B$ by setting $x=0$. Where do you have a difficulty ?

Comment: $\cos(nx)$ does not converge to $0$  (except for e very few values of $x$) so the infinite series is divergent, so you cannot sum it, or worse integrate it.

Comment: Your initial series has a meaning in distribution theory. Further integrals are handled in this older [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/121376/21783). Hoping this will help,